# How to draw an tiled background image with alpha transparency on iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone

When I use UIColor -colorWithPatternImage: to create a view with an tiled background pattern, everything that is supposed to be transparent appears to be black. Of course I can't assign clearColor to the background, since the background is already this pattern image UIColor object.

I believe that this internally is using CGContextDrawTiledImage function. Or must I go directly with CGContextDrawTiledImage in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have something in the back that is not transparent. Otherwise the backmost background (black) will show through your transparent image.

Claus

Comment: well, I draw the view over another which has colorful graphics. I need to have alpha there, to blend with this superview.